# The hostname i'm connected to changes when i connect to a certain network

Tags: linux, macos

Usually when I open terminal it'll show `kevin@kevins macbook pro`
or something like that but when I connect to a specific network it's showing me something else like `kevin@random-name` (some name i dont recognize). Why is this, and does this have any effect on my privacy. I'm connected to my jobs network.

Comment: Those are (probably) prompts, and they have no effect on your privacy. To answer further you should say more about how you connect to that specific network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use bash as shell. Please see `man bash` and look there for INVOCATION.

When you log-in via SSH, bash is invocated as a login shell. That means it executes the files `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile` (if found, in that order).

When you start the bash in a terminal, these files are executed: `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`. To maximize the confusion, the files may source (“include”) additional files, such as `/etc/profile.d/*`.

The prompt is set in the variable `$PS1`.

The simple way is to set the prompt in `~/.bash_profile` and you source this file in `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
    source ~/.bash_profile
fi
```